# Facets Categories: singular or plurals?

Tags: copywriting, labels

In labeling facets should the categories be plural or singular? Examples: years, authors, model, etc.?

Comment: English.SE *might* be a better place to ask. I'm sure there is a grammar rule in here somewhere.

Comment: Can you pick more than one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on whether the selection within each facet is mutually exclusive.

So *Author* if you can only select one author; *authors* is you can select more then one. Respectively, this can be seen as whether category items use checkboxes vs radio buttons / links.

Compare:

[image: A screenshot of the Monster job site, with facets showing checkboxes and plural form]

To:

[image: A screenshot of the Indeed job site, with facets showing links and singular form]

Comment: Indeed, because really for choices like "Job Types:" they're asking the question "Which job types would you like to filter by?" its just been truncated for ease of use. But the noun "job types" keeps it's plurality.

Answer (score 0):

Singular,

because the final selection is would read as Author : Christopher Alexander

Comment: I like this thought, but the selection could technically be plural right, like a year range 1994-2000? In that case would you want plural?